# Jenkins report plugin for WebdriverIo - Cucumber

Tags: jenkins, webdriver-io

I am using webdriver IO & Cucumber in my project. Any suggestions on jenkin report plugin that I can use apart from Allure as it is not available.

Comment: Hi, Question: Could you please give more info on `Allure as it is not available`. Because we use `WDIO with Cucumber and allure for reporting`. And it works fine on jenkins as well.

Comment: I agree. But our Jenkin management team refused to install the plugin, giving security reasons

Comment: Ok.. have you tried the JUNIT reporter?.. it might not have interactive UI as `Allure` but it can be handy